# Restrict user from accessing form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Good day everyone! I'm a python Django web app developer and I ran into a problem recently which is **to restrict a user from accessing a form twice untill after a given time.** I've tried using Django sessions.accessed but I don't get what I want. I would appreciate if anyone could help me out with this.

Comment: show me what you tried in your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Django session backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) is working on cookies. So, when you are make something like this in your view:

```py
def view(request):
    request.session["allow_access"] = False
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

the user can delete cookies or access via another browser or private mode.

So the best way is to use authentication of your users first and then you can work with sessions of your authenticated users with session backend.

```py
def view(request):
    ...
    if request.session.get("allow_access"):
        return HttpResponse(...)
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: Fannigurt thanks I'll try this and get back to you later